# How do I show a DDS image in a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

I've got a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app, and I'd like to display a DDS image. I tried simply doing this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Image Source="c:\sample.dds"  />
</Grid>
```

but nothing shows up. Is DDS not a valid image format for Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDS is not valid in Silverlight. Only JPEG and PNG are natively supported. The DDS image will need to be converted first or you'll need to get/develop an decoder (see http://imagetools.codeplex.com/ for example of .gif and .bmp decoders).